# Default initialize reference member without making it const

Tags: c++

I have a class with a reference member which is usually initialized explicitly in constructor. But for a test framework, I have to provide a default constructor without parameters. This means, I have to default-initialize the reference with a temporary. But in order to keep the temporary alive, I have to change the reference member to const ref. But this makes the this pointer of the reference object const so I cannot call non-const methods on it anymore.

Looks similar to this:

```
class Someclass
{
   public:
      Someclass() : m_Reference ( OtherClass() ) {}

   private:
      OtherClass & m_Reference;  <--- don't want to make this const so I can keep calling non const methods on it
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this without making everything mutable which would be ugly?

Regards

Comment: Mock the class? Wrap the class? Inherit the class? In all cases, create an actual non-temporary instance of `OtherClass` and use it for the reference. There's really no way around the fact that you must have an actual non-temporary instance to to be referenced.

Comment: `m_Reference` is `OtherClass &` and not `const OtherClass &`. It is not const, so you can call non-const member functions of `OtherClass`. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @WernerHenzeThe problem is using a temporary object for the initialization of the reference.

Comment: If the reference member is initialized only _usually_, then, maybe, that member shouldn't be a reference. A pointer sounds like a better option.

Comment: ```m_Reference ( OtherClass() )```
creates a temporary `OtherClass` object which ceases to exist before the constructor body even runs. Storing references is not advised. either use a pointer or a `reference_wrapper`

Comment: Not a solution, but just a thought: If you add extra code to your class, just so it can pass a test, what are you then really testing? Why add code that is not needed in production? Perhaps it is the test framework that is wrong?  :-) As a general rule, any code like `if (testing) doA(); else doB();` makes all the testing invalid.

Comment: As BoP says you are solving the wrong problem. But in case it comes up in some other instance: You can have a `static OtherClass dummy` and use a reference to `dummy`. But beware that this is then shared between all default initialized instances. As painful as it is you might have to use a `std::shared_ptr` and use `make_shared` in the default constructor. But really, don't do this just so your test framework can run.